# Files in directory sort by fileName ascending - for each

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

How to update my code so that all files are processed in order of date/time created?

```
Private Sub StartupFindExistingFiles(Path As String, SearchPattern As String)
    Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Path, SearchPattern)
    For Each fileName As String In fileEntries
        PrintJOBFile(fileName)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ with [`File.GetCreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim orderedByCreation = From file In Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path, SearchPattern)
                        Let createdAt = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file)
                        Order By createdAt Ascending
                        Select file

For Each filePath As String In orderedByCreation 
    PrintJOBFile(filePath)
Next
```

Note that you could also use `GetFiles` instead of `EnumerateFiles`. The latter can be more efficient.

Comment: i've changed to code to '.EnumerateFiles(Path, SearchPattern)'. I'm glad it works.

Comment: @Jim: i've fixed it already just a few seconds ago, it was a copy&paste issue from your code ;)

Comment: @Jim: i've learned it by doing. By using LINQ instead of loops in my own code or by answering LINQ qustions on Stackoverflow ;) Here are some suggestions, but i cannot confirm if these books are recommandable: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b8676ce5-abf7-4f8e-8add-1e60bb2240a1/best-book-for-c-linq-in-net?forum=csharpgeneral